# Find customer who bought least on W3schools SQL

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL Server and I'm trying to do some exercises. I want to find customers who bought least on W3schools database. My solution for this case is:

1. Join Customers with OrderDetails via CustomerID
2. Select CustomerNames that have least OrderID appeared after using JOIN.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderID), CustomerID
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY COUNT(CustomerID) ASC
HAVING COUNT(OrderID) = '1'
```

When I ran this query, message says "Syntax error near "Having". What happened with my query?
Please help me to figure out.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` clause has to come *after* the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: You say in your explanation that you join and then show the customer name. Your query does neither of the two things. Then, what does "bought least" mean? Your query looks for customers who placed exactly one order. That's more than zero orders. Then, how many products or pieces did they order? Is one order equal to ordering one piece of an item or are there order details you must take into consideration?

Answer (score 1):

> My solution for this case is:
>
> 1. Join Customers with OrderDetails via CustomerID
> 2. Select CustomerNames that have least OrderID appeared after using JOIN.

As @thorsten-kettner lamented:

> You say in your explanation that you join and then show the customer
> name. Your query does neither of the two things...

Furthermore, your question has severe grammatical errors making it hard to decipher.

> I want to find customers who bought least on W3schools database.

Nonetheless,

[The Try-SQL Editor at w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_columns)

1. To get the list of customers who have **at least** 1 order:

```sql
SELECT C.CustomerName FROM [Customers] AS C
JOIN [Orders] AS O
ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
GROUP BY C.CustomerID
ORDER BY C.CustomerName
```

2. To get the list of customers who have **exactly** 1 order:

```sql
SELECT C.CustomerName FROM [Customers] AS C
JOIN [Orders] AS O
ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
GROUP BY C.CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(O.OrderID) = 1
ORDER BY C.CustomerName
```

3. To get the customer who made the least number of orders:

*Including the ones who made no order. Use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` if you **only** want to consider the ones who made at least one order.*

*You can remove `LIMIT 1` to get the whole list sorted by the number of orders placed.*

```sql
SELECT C.CustomerName, COUNT(O.OrderID) FROM [Customers] AS C
LEFT JOIN [Orders] AS O
ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
GROUP BY C.CustomerID
ORDER BY COUNT(O.OrderID), C.CustomerName
LIMIT 1;
```

###### Addendum

As commented by @sticky-bit ,

The `ORDER BY` clause has to come *after* the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` query, something like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES CustomerID
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY COUNT(OrderID);
```

In case you are using MySQL, try the following version:

```sql
SELECT CustomerID
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(OrderID) = (
    SELECT COUNT(OrderID)
    FROM ORDERS
    GROUP BY CustomerID
    ORDER BY COUNT(OrderID)
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me some useful information. However, when I ran your query on W3schools, system still displayed a message "error near '1'". Maybe this website doesn't support this query?

Comment: I'm like 99% certain that my query is valid SQL Server syntax.  Are you certain that your engine/demo tool be running with SQL Server and not something else?

Comment: I've been running your query many time and this website always shows error message. I also edit syntax according to message but it still can't be run. I think it's not your query wrong. I will try again and find the solution.

Comment: This is valid SQL Server code, but isn't w3*ools using MySQL or something else?